# BSOD after waking up from sleep -- Critical process died

Tags: bsod, sleep, asus-laptop

Every time I shut the lid, I get a BSOD when waking up.
"Critical process died".

This is a new ASUS laptop X509JB with i5 10th gen, Nvidia graphics, running Windows 10 1909

I ran and installed Windows updates
I ran intel driver updater, and MYASUS tool for checking system and BSODs, and ndivia updater.
I see nothing marked in drivers
I rebooted, of course.
The only thing I can think of and didn't do is flash the BIOS. But this is a new model, it is i5 10th gen, it can't come with an old, decrepit Mobo and firmware, right? It could be half a year old at the most.

Comment: Send it in for warranty repairs.

Comment: Warranty repair is a good idea. Also see if you can get (from the ASUS Support site only) BIOS, Chipset and Power Driver for your laptop. Apply these and see if that helps.

Comment: Even a new laptop could have been manufactured some time ago. The BIOS could have been updated since then. You should also check in the Event Viewer which process died,

Comment: I downloaded chipset but I don't see an installer among the files. I can't figure out how to install it

Comment: In event viewer I see a few things: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52}
 and APPID 
{4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: Another: The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000007a (0xffffd280dc6feeb8, 0xffffffffc000000e, 0x000000022c7868c0, 0xfffff8064f59bdae). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: ca00f522-6407-4899-a902-31d1b36564d2.

Comment: Another: The driver \Driver\WudfRd failed to load for the device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_8A03&SUBSYS_1EC11043&REV_03\3&11583659&0&20.

Comment: Not sure if warranty will cover it because I bought it without Windows. They can claim it is a Windows problem...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing Intel Rapid Storage Technology

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/downloads/eula/29339/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-User-Interface-and-Driver?httpDown=https%3A%2F%2Fdownloadmirror.intel.com%2F29339%2Feng%2FSetupRST.exe

Since then I have not seen issues when the computer wakes up from sleep.